# Avoid case sensitive in SSH commands

Tags: php, ssh

I have cloned my GitHub repo to the server and for running second command i have finding folder issue:

## Logic

Repository will clone to the server in new folder matched name as repo name like:

```
public_html > Resto
```

Then I need to enter that `Resto` folder in order to run my second command but it returns

```
No such file or directory
```

## Code

```
$command1 = 'cd '.$destination.''; //get public_html folder
$command2 = 'git clone '.$repos->repository.''; //clone repo in public_html (it creates new folder same as repo name)
$command3 = 'cd '.$repos->name.''; //get repo name and enter new folder same as repo name
$command4 = 'composer install'; //run new command in repo folder
```

## Issue

The issue here is GitHub give the names like `resto` and folder made in my `public_html` is named like `Resto` so there is capital `R` involved.

## What I need

I need to let my `$command3` ignore case sensitivity and enter that folder regardless of capital `R` or if there is any space in folder name (for other clones in future)

**How do I do that?**

Comment: Instead of "how do I make my code use the wrong name without error", why not ask "how to use the correct name" instead? Where does `$repos->name` come from? And did you know about the next parameter to `git clone`?

Comment: `$repos->name` comes from github ssh https link it's the name of repository

Comment: @Amadan my clone part works just fine, it clones my repository. my issue is in entering that repository folder

Comment: what's the exact value of `$repos->repository`. Neither github nor git randomly capitalise letters.

Comment: I mean, if you do `git clone '.$repos->repository.' '.$repos->name;`, you would get the directory named the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify where to clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone):

```
git clone <repository> [<directory>]
```

Comment: would that enter the directory automatically?